# GUI Builder for eclipse juno 4.2

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-juno, gui-builder

Do you know nice GUI builder for eclipse juno 4.2? I would be really appreciated to use Eclipse, not Netbeans.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!
K4sia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try WindowBuilder.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

If it isn't part of your Eclipse install already, you can find it in the Juno plugin repository.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

In case you are not familiar with installing plugins from an online plugins repository, you access the repositories via a dialog accessible from Help -> Install New Software. Note that it is going to take a while for the dialog to display the repository content. Once it does, search for WindowBuilder.